# How to make frame to a transparent background image in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency

I have some images with a transparent background like this:

[image]

So, when applying it somewhere it looks like that:

[image]

And all i want to is add a frame around it to looks like that :

[image]

So, how can i do that ?

Comment: Hey, welcome to GD. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Create a rounded-edges square on Photoshop, put it above the image you desire.

2- Reduce its "Fill" to 0% (not the opacity)

3- Open the Layer Style window for this shape, add a 2px white stroke for example and click Ok

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

*Create a new layer

*Fill in a color that is different than the color
   you want for the border

*Fx --> stroke --> inside (use the color you
   want the border in for the stroke

*Fill at 0%

*Done.

Comment: Rachel, could you explain how this answer is different from Amr's?

Comment: I did not understand what he meant by "Create a rounded-edges square on Photoshop" when I was looking for an answer yesterday.  I do now after poking and prodding through Photoshop.  This is yet another way.  Instead of adding a rectangle you fill in a blank layer and add a stroke.  It's the same basic idea but the means of getting the fill layer is different.